# Regex to ignore line with specific text

Tags: regex

I have the following line in an XHTML file: `ri:content-title="Test Title Rename"/>`

I also have lines that looked something similar to this: `ri:content-title="Test Title Outside ri:space-key="Test"/>`

I'm trying to put together a regex that will search for the `"/>` but ignore lines that contain `ri:space`.

Using `"(?!\s)` allows me to skip the one part where there is the `" ri"`, but I guess I don't know how to ignore a whole line. The trick with this is that I'm wanting to replace the `"/>` with a suffix, for example `3.12"/>` but I don't want to replace the line that contains `ri:space`

Please note I'll be using this regex with a command line tool for mass-updating Confluence pages.

Below is an excerpt from the XHTML source reader:

```
<h2>Macro Update Test</h2>
<p>Below is the text and other elements.</p>
<p>
  <ac:macro ac:name="pagetree">
    <ac:parameter ac:name="root">Test Title Change Rename</ac:parameter>
  </ac:macro>
</p>
<p>Title and return link to <ac:link>
    <ri:page ri:content-title="Test Title Rename"/>
  </ac:link> should be updated.</p>
<p>Link to external location: <ac:link>
    <ri:page ri:content-title="Test Title Outside" ri:space-key="Test"/>
  </ac:link>.</p>
```

Comment: Please link the regex you wrote.

Comment: It's in the question: All I've gotten so far is `"(?!\s)`

Comment: It's not very clear. If a tag contains ri:content-title and not ri:space, it should match, right? If a tag doesn't contain ri:content-title, should it match? If a tag contains ri:space-foobar, should it match? Please provide more examples and expected outputs covering the limits of your problem. And check your double-quotes ;)

Comment: It should only match if it contains `ri:content-title`. If it contains any other `ri:`, then it should not match that line. The tag has to contain `ri:content-title`

Comment: The rules are really too complex for a regex. Try with an XML/HTML parser instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that. The only way I can update this material is through a command line interface, so I'm a bit limited.

Comment: `xsltproc` is a command-line tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
 #  (ri:content-title\s*=\s*"[^"]*)"\s*/>     

 (                                  # (1 start)
      ri:content-title
      \s* = \s* 
      "
      [^"]* 
 )                                  # (1 end)

 " \s* 
 />
```

Comment: That works for finding the whole line. But I need to just grab the end of it `"/>` and change it to `3.1 "/>` for example. I'm beginning to see that doing this with regex may not fully work, so my options will become limited.

Comment: @EustaceMonk - What? Just find `(ri:content-title\s*=\s*"[^"]*)"\s*/>`, replace with `${1}3.1 "/>` and besides parsing markup with regex quandry, there is nothing a regex won't match in terms of a string. Even if the phrase is before or after or in the middle or wherever.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the regex engine you use, I give you a pattern in a raw style and let you escape what need to be:

```
<\w+(?:[^"r>/]+|"(?>[^"]+|\\{2}|\\.)*"|\Br|r(?!i:[a-z]))*ri:content-title=(?:[^"r>/]+|"(?>[^"]+|\\{2}|\\.)*"|\Br|r(?!i:[a-z]))/>
```

As triplee suggests it if you have some tools that can deals with XML...